"The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)" Flutter Firestore
I'm a noob to development and StackOverflow but I have attempted looking at multiple solutions unfortunately nothing is working as intended. I'm getting the error: Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)
This happens when I'm trying to Sign Up using Username, Email and Password. I have attached my SignUpController class snippet
Future<bool> usernameExists(String username) async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('username', isEqualTo: username)
        .get();
    return querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty;
  }

And my Firestore rules
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

I have also followed the ChatGPT solution to update the Firestore rules which also did not seem to work
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false; // Deny all write operations
    }
  }
}


My apologies for the "enter image description here". I was unaware of it as I'm new to StackOverflow

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

When you post the code-as-text, as Doug asked, also take a moment to in that code prove that it meets the conditions that your rules set. In other words: check if there's a signed in user, right before calling to Firestore.

@DougStevenson Thank you I did not read through the rules here thoroughly and will be careful next time.

@FrankvanPuffelen I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by a signed in user. I'm trying to create a new user by signing up and as soon as I click the sign up, it gives me this error

Please don't wait until next time - edit the question to show your code as properly formatted text.

I have updated the question. Hope I did it right

Your rules require that if request.auth != null, but your code doesn't verify that this is true in any way. How do you know that a user is signed in when your get() call executes (hint: there isn't).

Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
